# Extra fields in Django ModelForms: I can see them, but cannot save them to the model. Why?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

In my Django application, I am using a ModelForm to get my user to enter a street address. 
I want clean this address, perform USPS validation on it, then geocode it. If all those steps succeed, I would like to save the dirty and cleaned version into my `Location` model which is shown below.

```
from localflavor.us.us_states import US_STATES
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class Location(models.Model):
    # I want the user to enter these fields using a Model Form
    streetAddress = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=300)
    city = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False,  max_length=50)
    state = USStateField(choices = US_STATES, null=False,)
    zip = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=10, )

    # I want to automatically derive these fields without any user intervention.
    # These fields are going to be calculated during the form validation process. 
    cleanedStreetAddress = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=300)
    cleanedCity = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True,  max_length=50)
    cleanedState = USStateField(choices = US_STATES, null=False,)
    cleanedZip5 = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=5, )
    cleanedZip4 = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=4, )
    geoCoords = models.PointField(null=False, blank=False,)
```

In my corresponding ModelForm (named `LocationForm`), I have `fields = ["streetAddress", "city", "state", "zip",]`. I populate the remaining 6 fields by manually adding them to the dictionary being returned by the `LocationForm.clean()` method. So far, so good. No problems.

In the corresponding class based view, I process the form in the `form_valid()` method, like this:

```
class InputLocationView(FormView):
    template_name = "helloWorld.html"
    form_class = LocationForm
    success_url = "/helloWorld"


    def form_valid(self, form):
        print "form.cleaned_data = %s" % form.cleaned_data
        ###
        # Output of the line above: 
        # form.cleaned_data = {'cleanedZip4': '0000', 'streetAddress': u'123 Main Street', 
        # 'zip': u'90210', 'cleanedStreetAddress': '123 MAIN ST', 'cleanedState': 'CO',
        # 'geoCoords': <Point object at 0x10a1b4e20>, 'state': u'CO', 'city': u'Anytown',
        # 'cleanedCity': 'ANYTOWN', 'cleanedZip5': '90210'}
        ###
        print "form.cleaned_data['geoCoords'] = (%s, %s)" % (form.cleaned_data['geoCoords'].x, form.cleaned_data['geoCoords'].y)
        # Output of the line above: form.cleaned_data['geoCoords'] = (-77.260768, 39.113707)

        newLocation = form.save(commit=False)
        newLocation.save()
```

As you can see from my comments above, the derived data that I added in the LocationForm.clean() is present in the class-based-view. That's good news. However, when it gets to newLocation.save(), it blows up with the following error:

```
null value in column "geoCoords" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (3, 123 Main Street, , Anytown, CO, 90210, , null,
 , , , null)
```

Why is `newLocation.save()` not including any of my derived data, when clearly all that data is present in the `form.cleaned_data` dictionary? How do I make sure **all** the data from `form.cleaned_data` makes it into the SQL Insert statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ModelForm` machinery probably only fills in the instance fields you specified in `fields`. The way I would approach this problem is by overriding `ModelForm.save()`. Something like this:

```
class LocationForm(ModelForm):
    ...
    def save(self, commit=True, **kwargs):
        # create the instance but don't commit it to the database
        location = super(LocationForm, self).save(commit=False, **kwargs)

        # now set your cleaned fields on the model instance
        location.cleanedStreetAddress = ...

        if commit: 
            location.save() 

        return location
```

See the [documentation on `save()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) for more information.

Comment: Instead of Kevin Henry's approach, I changed `newLocation = form.save(commit=False)` in the class-based-view to `newLocation = Location(**form.cleaned_data)`. It works and it seems cleaner and more elegant. Is there any reason I shouldn't use this technique?

Comment: @SaqibAli: My idea of elegant is to reuse the code Django already provides for turning a form into a model instance. If you look at the [code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/deed00c0d803d324a3dfdeba52458b6b009c1a90/django/forms/models.py#L36) you will see that it is far more robust - it can accommodate M2M fields, it has error handling, it knows to look at `FileFields` last so they can use the other values, etc. If your solution works for your use case then go for it, but my recommendation would be to reuse Django's code when possible.

Answer (score 0):

Only the fields named in the `ModelForm.Meta.fields` list are automatically assigned from `cleaned_data`, if I am not mistaken.  Instead of putting your derived data into `cleaned_data` you should just set the directly on `self.instance` in your `ModelForm`.

Comment: Like this? `self.instance["geoCoords"] = BlahBlahBlah`?
It didn't work. I got this error: `'Location' object does not support item assignment`.

Comment: It is a Location object, you just assign its members. No dictionary here.  E.g. `self.instance.geoCoords = BlahBlahBlah`.